# Which part of this C code is missing or needs to be altered?

Tags: c, assembly, switch-statement

For my assignment, I have to fill in missing parts of the C code below. 
However, I am not sure which parts are missing or which part I have to fill in.
I have a sample assembly code which this code will generate, but do not know which parts I have to change to get my expected result. I am just looking for clarification.

```
typedef enum {MODE_A, MODE_B, MODE_C, MODE_D, MODE_E} mode_t;
long switch3 (long *p1, long *p2, mode_t action) {
  long result = 0;
  switch(action){
  case MODE_A:
  case MODE_B:
  case MODE_C:
  case MODE_D:
  case MODE_E:
  default;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Other points:

- There may be cases that should be written in the C
  code with a fall-through
- Code shows branching on an enumerated type value in a switch
  statement. (Question: what exactly does this mean in simple terms? My professor provided a complex definition that I do not understand.)

**Assembly code result example:**

```
# p1 in %rdi, p2 in %rsi, action in %edx
.L2:                         # MODE_E
      movl    $27, %eax
      ret
.L7:                         # MODE_A
      movl    (%rsi), %rax
      movq    (%rdi), %rdx
      movq     %rdx, (%rsi)
      ret
.L5:                         # MODE_B
      movq     (%rdi), %rax
      addq     (%rsi), %rax
      movq      %rax, (%rdi)
      ret
.L4:                         # MODE_C
      movq     $59, (%rdi)
      movq     (%rsi), %rax
      ret
.L3:                         # MODE_D
      movq     (%rsi), %rax
      movq      %rax, (%rdi)
      movl      $27, %eax
      ret
.L8:                         # default
      movl      $12, %eax
      ret
```

Comment: "branching on an enumerated type value in a switch statement" means `switch(action)`, where `action` is an enum

Comment: You need to add code for each of the possible modes in all the `case` fields.

Comment: You're going to have to explain what your expected result is

Comment: What is an example of such mode? I am very unfamilar with C coding
.

Comment: *...my assignment* - exactly. *Yours*. Look at the assembly, understand the logic constructs, and determine how you would do it in C to obtain the same constructs.

Comment: I don't know if it matters, but I'm just curious for my own knowledge; but aren't `*_t` types/typenames reserved?

Comment: @WhozCraig Yeah it's my assignment. I am not asking anyone to do it for me, I am just looking for clarification.

Comment: @Prosze Ah, well in that case, yeah, pretty much what I said. Understanding how, if you were crafting the code-emission of a compiler, how would a switch like the one shown possess code that would ultimately wind up looking like that assembly. And that "fall-through" hint is important, btw.

Comment: @RastaJedi I am not sure how to send files on here, but our instructor only provided us with this paper copy. That is awesome that you like to do this in your free time

Comment: @Prosze thanks for the example code in the updated question. What architecture are you using for compiling? Are you using GCC?

Comment: @RastaJedi Yes GCC

Comment: In the assembly code, there is a `ret` at the end of each case, so there are no cases that should be written in the C code with a fall-through.

Comment: @barakmanos Are you sure there shouldn't be any fall-throughs? Whozcraig Stated that it's an important hint

Comment: @RastaJedi: "fall-through" means no `break` at the end of a `case` (so it's falling through to the next case).

Comment: @Pauline: I'm not sure, but I see `ret` in every case. What do you think?

Comment: Side note #2: Why is there a down-vote on this question??? That's why I've stopped posting questions here. Too many smart @$$es on this website.

Comment: Your prof quoted "Watch out for the cases" regarding fall-through. I don't think there are any cases (referring the Assembly given) like that here.

Comment: @RastaJedi How do I see that there is a downvote? All I see are the upvotes

Comment: @Abhineet I did not think there were either. Just like barak manos stated, there is `ret` in every case.

Comment: @RastaJedi - What do you mean? And you do know, that SO is not a social chatting community, right? I apologize if I am offensive but it seems that your comments have clouded this page.

Comment: there is at least one fall-thu, case D 's " mov ax,27" is from case E. so the c-code for "D" has no break, and E is obviously just "return 27;"

Comment: @Tommylee2k: The assembly code is implemented **without any fall-through's**. It is true, however, that one can "optimize" and implement those two cases that you've mentioned with a fall-through, as one of them is a post-fix of the other. I've used double- quotes on "optimize" because it hardly optimizes anything (apart from code size).

Comment: @Pauline: With sufficient rating (which you currently lack of), one can click the question's grade and see up-votes vs down-votes (currently 9:-1).

Comment: as far as i've understood the prof, he provides an assembly code, and want the studend to add code to the original C-Code, that would produce assembly like the provided one; at least that's the only way the lesson makes sense to me ;-P
not the ASM has the fallthrough, the C code has

Comment: @Pauline: Do you have *complete* asm output for the whole function?  The snippet you posted is all that's needed to answer the assignment, but I'm wondering about my theory that `MODE_E` is first because it's reached after falling through conditional branches checking for the other cases.  (And that's why it duplicates the `mov/ret` from the end of the `MODE_D` case instead of having fall-through in the asm).

Comment: I had never used `switch` with an enum before. That is quite a cool use for an enum to be honest.

Answer (score 8):

As it's an assignment, I won't give you the code. But here is a clarification about those 2 points.

A `switch() case` can **generally** be seen as a block like:

```
if(myvar == ...){
    //branch1
} else if(myvar == ...){
    //branch2
}
...
```

Each `if` is a branch and in your case, each branch condition depends on an Enum value. That should answer the `branching on an enumerated type value in a switch statement` question.

I wrote "generally" because, in fact  a `switch case` is more like a asm `jump if equals`. so once it reach the correct `case` all the following code will be executed, even the code in the next `case`statements. You have to handle this by stopping programmatically the `switch` block (You either break it or return). That's for the `fall-through` point.

You can find plenty of site explaining how a `switch case` works.

Now you have to fill each `case`with the correct implementation -- it seems to be permutations.

Comment: @Prosze Note that you don't need a `break` after the default case. (It doesn't hurt to put it there and a lot of people do; I don't, not that it matters, just preference).

Comment: @RastaJedi, But you do need it if the default case isn't last :)

Comment: Yeah, @StoryTeller is right; whichever case is last is the one that doesn't necessarily need a `break`.

Comment: @RastaJedi, it's more than preference actually. Code can change and move, a switch may be restructured. If you like me do copy & paste for this, a missing break may stay missing, [and you'll end up with a bug in your code](http://nethack.wikia.com/wiki/Yeenoghu).

Comment: @RastaJedi, they haven't created the Vim plugin that protects you from human error, yet. When they do, please let me know. I'll stop being overly cautious.

Comment: @StoryTeller Which is why compilers should have the option to only allow MISRA C styled `switch` statements: `break` after every (group of) cases, no code before the first case label, `default` case must be present, and curly brackets are preferred in most situations.

Answer (score 6):

It's not really clear. But from what I understand, the professor provided an assembly code, and a C code 
I think he wants you to extend the C-Code in that way, that compiling it would produce an assembly code similar to the one he provided.

i hope i didn't messed it up (i've major problems reading the AT&T syntax), but for me this looks like:

```
typedef enum {MODE_A, MODE_B, MODE_C, MODE_D, MODE_E} mode_t;
long switch3 (long *p1, long *p2, mode_t action) {
  long result = 0;
  switch(action){
    case MODE_A:  result = *p2; *p2 = *p1; break;
    case MODE_B:  result = *p2; *p1 = *p1 + *p2; break;
    case MODE_C:  result = *p2; *p1 = 59; break;
    case MODE_D: *p1 = *p2;  // fallthru to E
    case MODE_E: result = 27 break;
    default: result = 12;
  }
  return result;
}
```

"There may be cases that should be written in the C code with a fall-through" for me is a hint that

```
    case MODE_D: *p1 = *p2;  // fallthru to E
    case MODE_E: result = 27 break;
```

should be written, and not

```
    case MODE_D: *p1 = *p2;  result = 27 break;
    case MODE_E: result = 27 break;
```

(which would have the same result) even tho the compiler chose another label for this

Comment: You should definitely add `return result` at the end of every `case` (or at the end of the `switch` statement).

Comment: if you look at the code in the OPs post, you can see this is done after the switch, I just changed the switch statement, not the whole function

Comment: but obviously that's not obvious, i'll extend the answer to cover the complete original c-code

Comment: I don't agree with your `MODE_D` case. There is a `ret` instruction in the OP asm code so here should be a `break;`

Comment: ah ok, and the code created always 100% represents the code it was created on? I doubt the prof points to fallthroug, if there were none ... the asm also doesnt represent the (unneeded) "result" variable, which is optimzed away in asm, but exists in C-Code. instead of break out of the switch, asm returns out of the function. Another hint is that "MODE_E" is rearanged by the compiler to be the first case

Comment: Its a assembly code result "example". If you write a solution that produces the same logic output as the assembler snippet, then the work should be done. Using such fall-through statements shows the power of higher level languages, so if I were the professor I would give a bonus for such constructs.

Comment: putting the .L2  label directly before the "movl    $27, %eax" after .L3  would've implemented the same "power" in assembler ... there's nothing magical about it

Comment: @jhamon:  My guess: The compiler used a sequence of branches to implement the `switch`, not a jump table.  `case MODE_E` is last, so execution probably reaches `.L2` after falling through all the conditional branches.  If the fall-through wasn't from the 2nd last to last C case, there would probably be fall-through in the asm as well.

Comment: You are right, I read this answer along with the edited question and the part about code optimization is missing in the question.